# Integration of a and b integral

Tags: integration

I'm trying to solve this integral $$\int \frac{x^a}{1+x^b}dx $$ I'm not sure how I should approach this.I've looked up for similar integrals but nothing seems to apply to this.Any help?I'm thinking of Leibniz rule but not sure how to apply

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, we can do this by factoring the denominator and writing in partial fractions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to the world of [hypergeometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function)
$$\int \frac{x^a}{1+x^b}dx=\frac{x^{a+1} }{a+1}\, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{a+1}{b};\frac{a+b+1}{b};-x^b\right)$$

**Edit**

It is possible that, without noticing it, you already used them. Being simplistic, use the well known series
$$\frac 1{1+t}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n t^n$$ Make $t=x^b$ to get
$$\frac{x^a}{1+x^b}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  (-1)^n x^{a+b n}$$
$$\int \frac{x^a}{1+x^b}dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{a+b n+1}}{a+b n+1}$$

Comment: so no way of solving this with Leibniz? I'm asking because I didn't get to hypergeometric functions yet

Comment: @Lola. Then, as GEdgar commented, use partial fraction decomposition and ... have fun if $b$ is large ! Cheers.